# code to check whichever interpreter pycharm is using

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, remote-server

i'd love to have a way to check whenever i'm using the remote interpreter or the local one.
i'd need to check it on my code in order to properly set some variables.

eg.

```
if REMOTE_INTERPRETER:
    data_path = '/data'
else:
    data_path = '/nas/data'
```

i already found a workaround to check if i'm executing the code in debug or not like

```
try:
    import pydevd
    PYCHARM_DEBUG = True
except ImportError:
    PYCHARM_DEBUG = False
```

but i can't really find a way to automatically understand which interpreter i'm using.

Comment: may be check hostname and ip?

Comment: that's nice,

import socket and check socket.gethostname()
is a working solution! thanks